# switch to parallel coding

Tags: multithreading, math, parallel-processing, high-speed-computing

we all writing code for single processor.
i wonder when we all are able to write code on multi processors?

what do we need (software tools, logic, algorithms) for this switching?

edit: in my view, as we do many task parallely, same way we need to convert those real life solutions(algorithms) to computer lang. just as OOPs coding did for procedural coding. OOPs is more real life coding style than procedural one. so i hope for that kind of solutions.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most important requirement is a good language that has native constructs that support parallelism or one that can automatically generate parallel code. There are quite a few languages that fit that description, but none of them is popular enough to really be considered for mainstream use. That, in turn is caused by several things:

1. By their very nature, these languages are very different from today's imperative languages, and are therefor harder to learn (or at least seem that way).
2. They often lack good tools and libraries, making them unusable for any "real" project.

Of course, if it were more popular more people would be willing to learn it and there would be more support, so it's a kind of cycle that's pretty hard to break out of. I guess all we can do is hope. :)

An example of a language designed with heavy parallelization in mind is Erlang - and it's actually used in commercial projects.

Answer (score 4):

What we need are natural abstractions for highly-concurrent algorithms.  Actors (think: Erlang) go a long way in this direction, but they aren't a one-size-fits-all solution.  Some more specific abstractions like fork/join or map/reduce can be even easier to apply to common problems.

The trick with all of these concurrency abstractions is they require functional-style programming.  Concurrency doesn't mesh well with shared mutable state.  As they say, "Locks considered harmful".  Since most developers come from a strictly imperative background, switching to a shared-nothing continuation passing approach is often extremely challenging.

Incidentally, with respect to concurrency abstractions, Clojure has some very interesting features in this direction.  Not only does it have sort-of actors, but it also defines a transactional memory model (think: databases) along with a global, atomic references mechanism.  These two features allow concurrent operations to share "mutable" state without ever having to worry about locking or race conditions.

In the end, it comes down to education.  Much of the needed theoretical work into concurrency abstractions has already been done, we just need to accept it.  Unfortunately, as Erlang and Haskell prove, sometimes the best ideas remain relegated to an extremely fringe demographic.  Hopefully efforts like Scala and Clojure will succeed in bringing the more advanced abstractions into the mainstream by sneaking them onto an existing, well-supported platform (the JVM).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for massive concurrent programming - unless there is a breakthrough in compilers to help, we will be throwing out a lot of what we know about algorithms (I think Don Knuth even said that). Read about Erlang for a glimpse of this possible future.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools/languages that are popular or are gaining popularity.  If you use FORTRAN, C, or C++, you can use [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/) (not too hard to implement) or the [Message Passing Interface](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/mpi/) (MPI) libraries (powerful and greatest speedup potential, but also complex and difficult).  OpenMP uses preprocessor directives to mark areas that can be parallelized, especially loops.  MPI uses messages that pass data back and forth between processes, and the greatest difficulty is keeping everything synchronized without hitting bottlenecks and keeping processes waiting.  I would say MPI is definitely on the way out, however.  It's become clear in the scientific/high-performance computing communities that the speedup is rarely worth the additional development time.

As for up and coming languages, check out [Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language)).  It's still being designed, but the goal is to create a language even easier for scientific computing than FORTRAN.  Programs will be specified in a very high level mathematical syntax.  Additionally, parallelism will be implicit; the programmer will have to work to do things in serial.  Plus, it's being championed by Sun and is based on java, so it will be portable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer, and in many ways even the complex answers are currently inadequate or incomplete.  You'll get a better answer if you are more specific about the replies you want: pointers to dev libraries and tools, instructional materials, pointers to current research projects and issues in this area, or something else?

Comment: in my view, as we do many task parallely, same way we need convert those real life solutions(algorithms) to computer lang.

just as OOPs coding did for procedural coding. OOPs is more real life coding style than procedural one.

so i hope for that kind of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The most important requirement is to be able to split your problem into smaller problems that can be solved independently of each other. Once you've worked out how you're going to do that, everything else is easier to think about and further questions of implementation (e.g. "parts of my calculation depend on other parts - how do I wait for them to have finished?") become concrete, specific things you can research or ask here about.

Answer (score 0):

for java you can now look to Parallel Java Library or DPJ(deterministic Parallel Java!)
It will offer you great help in extracting parallelism from codes!!